# Error in Java application

Tags: java, joptionpane

#### Code in the action listener of Save Button:

```
i= Integer.parseInt(txt_userid.getText());
s= txt_pass.getText();
n = txt_name.getText();
Try
{
    if(txt_userid.getText().isEmpty() || (txt_pass.getText().isEmpty() || txt_name.getText().isEmpty())))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incomplete input!");
    }
    else{
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        rs.updateInt("USERID", i);
        rs.updateInt("PASSWORD", s);
        rs.updateInt("NAME", n);
        rs.insertRow():
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(UserAccountForm.this, "Record Saved"):
        }
} catch(SQLException err)
{
    System.out.println(err.get message());
}
```

My problem is that when one or two text field are left empty the information typed must not save and must pop the message dialog "Incomplete input". It works perfectly fine for `txt_pass` and `txt_name` which are both string, but whenever I left the text field (`txt_userid`) empty it gives me an error. Why is that?

Comment: When I left the textfield (txt_userid) empty it does not show the dialog box ("Incomplete Input!").

Comment: Create and post your [mcve] so we can see what is wrong with real code.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: slr, yes. txt_pass and txt_name are varchar type while txt_userid is decimal/integer type

Comment: You're completely ignoring the questions above. No one asked the database type. You mentioned an error in your original program, and we're trying to find out what error, but you won't tell us. Why?

Comment: @manetsus: I got it by not giving terrible answers. Please fix your answer. It's dangerous and stupid code, and the newbie thinks you know what you're doing which makes it even more dangerous. And I don't give a flip about the rep. I'll give a correct answer that's a community wiki (i.e., that gives me no rep), as long as we can post a decent answer for this question.

Comment: No, your code is worse than a compilation error. At least a compilation error will prevent bad code from running. Yours will compile and run, and exceptions will be thrown, but **will be ignored**, meaning the program will explode and the coder and user will never know why. Seriously, if you don't know about how or why to handle exceptions, please don't answer questions that involve them.

Comment: Finally. Thank you. Now @manetsus, please read the [exceptions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) to see why this really is an important distinction.

Comment: That not the case here what you are saying. `Exception` could be ignored easily if it is not needed. However, I edited my post, because I have respect to the respected person like you. And I am sorry for my bad language. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, you can avoid it by checking first whether it is `null` or not. Change the portion:

```
if(txt_userid.getText().isEmpty() || (txt_pass.getText().isEmpty() || txt_name.getText().isEmpty())))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incomplete input!");
}
```

to:

```
if(txt_userid.getText()==null || txt_pass.getText()==null || txt_name.getText()==null || txt_userid.getText().isEmpty() || txt_pass.getText().isEmpty() || txt_name.getText().isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incomplete input!");
}
```

In addition, add a `try-catch`, before the existing `try-catch`.

Change:

```
i= Integer.parseInt(txt_userid.getText());
s= txt_pass.getText();
n = txt_name.getText();
```

to:

```
try
{
    i= Integer.parseInt(txt_userid.getText());
    s= txt_pass.getText();
    n = txt_name.getText();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // at least do it right
}
```

Comment: It's still not working for the txt_userid :( txt_userid is in decimal type ,do decimal and string have the same code for this?

Comment: is not `txt_userid` a button? please, provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: txt_userid, txt_pass, txt_ name are variable name for textfield.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try this. but one question, ain't you getting any compilation error for having capital 'T' in `Try` of `try-catch` in your code??

Comment: Its okay. However, confirm me is it working or not. If it is not working, then provide the exception/error details.